# MIPS ASSEMBLY split up a number

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

We have a little homework in MIPS ASSEMBLER to do, and I have a question to a little problem I have encountered.
Somewhere in my Code I HAVE to split up a number into 2 registers.
Is there an elegant way to do it? I really was thinking about it, and the only thing that comes to mind is the **and** or **andi** operator.
Somehow it doesnt work for me, I dont know why, maybe I understand it wrong.
We have a 6 bit Number, where the first 3 bits are the one number I have to extract, and the last 3 bits are the second number.

```
#-----split x and y-----#
andi $a2, $a0, 000111 # x--> a2
andi $a3, $a0, 111000 # y--> a3
```

Is this the correct way of thinking about it?
Why doesnt it work?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Think of how to do it in a language you know and then later take that approach to assembly.  You don't have to think in assembly, which is hard when you don't know it.

Comment: I actually dont have a clue how to cut a number into 2 pieces. D,:

Comment: Ok, think about it in decimal: let's say you have the number 23, and you want to extract 2, separate from 3.  How might you do it using math?

Comment: OHH, okay, so the idea is to use the modulo operator? 23%10, and 23/10%10
And bitwise you do it with 2?

Comment: Ok, next there's the idea of shifting.  Shifting 1 digit left is like multiplying by the number base.  So, 23 * 10 = 230 (decimal shifting left).  And 23 / 10 = 2 (decimal shifting right).  By shifting we can slide digits around.  In C, Java there are shift operators.  Also in MIPS.

Comment: Okay, thats what I would call elegent.
So, if I wanted to split the number 0B 110 101, I would shift left 3 digits for 101, and 3 right for 110?

Comment: Since the 101 is already in the proper position, you just want to clear the upper bits.  That's where your ANDI would work.  For the 110, yes, shift right by 3 digits.  If there were unwanted bits still, you would also and, for example, if the number was 11110101 and you wanted the 110, then shift right by 3 followed by the same ANDI to clear them.

Comment: The other approach is to shift left to first left justify the field in a word (that removes unwanted bits above the bits of interest) and then shift right to right justify (which also removes bits below the bits of interest).  That will also isolate a group of bits.  For example, with 11 110 101, if you shift left by 32-6=26 you'll have 110 101 0000000..., then shift right by 29 and you'll have just the 110.  (These processors can shift by any amount in one instruction / one cycle, so while it may seem like a lot of shifting, its inexpensive.)

Comment: Yes, correct way of thinking about it, you just need to write your constants correctly.  `000111` is still in decimal, so it's one hundred and eleven, not `0b111` = seven.  IDK if MARS allows base-2 numbers in source code you you might need hex.

Comment: Yeah, i figured that out after 3 hours of not getting it. xD
Thanks anyway mate <3